# Get JSON attributes using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This is my **test.json** file :

```
[{"id":"12","url":"http:\/\/localhost\/test\/1\/images\/pic\/3.jpg"},
{"id":"11","url":"http:\/\/localhost\/test\/1\/images\/pic\/1.png"},
{"id":"10","url":"http:\/\/localhost\/test\/1\/images\/pic\/2.png"}]
```

I want to print it on *emphasized text* using jQuery.

```
<div>12<img src="http://localhost/test/1/images/pic/3jpg" /></div>
<div>11<img src="http://localhost/test/1/images/pic/1jpg" /></div>
<div>10<img src="http://localhost/test/1/images/pic/2jpg" /></div>
```

Comment: This is not a valid JSON.

Comment: Please, change the tittle of the question for another one which give people a best idea about what do you need. "Need help in java/c++/maven/linux/jason" doesn't give further information that the labels "java, c++, maven, linux, or jason".

Comment: I'd go with the classic formula: What did you try? What didn't work? It will be easier to answer you then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get your `json` from the server rather than hard-coding it into your javascript, use jquery's `.getJSON()` method ([see docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)).  Then iterate over the response data using the `.each()` method ([see docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)).

```
$.getJSON(
    'test.json',
    function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
            el = $('<div>' + obj['id'] + '<img src="'+ obj['url'] +'" /></div>');
            $('body').append(el);
        });
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the valid JSON bellow and try to reformat yours like it, you can find also example that show you how you can parse a JSON Object using `for in` to acheive the desired result.

Hope this helps.

```js
var test_json = 
[
   {"id":"12","url":"http:\/\/localhost\/test\/1\/images\/pic\/3.jpg"},
   {"id":"11","url":"http:\/\/localhost\/test\/1\/images\/pic\/1.png"},
   {"id":"10","url":"http:\/\/localhost\/test\/1\/images\/pic\/2.png"}
];

for ( var key in test_json )
{
    console.log('<div>'+test_json[key].id+'<img src="'+test_json[key].url+'" /></div>');
}
```